# Dynamically allocated shared memory in CUDA. Execution Configuration

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

What does Nvidia mean [by this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#execution-configuration)?

> `Ns` is of type `size_t` and specifies the number of bytes in shared
> memory that is dynamically allocated per block for this call in
> addition to the statically allocated memory; this dynamically
> allocated memory is used by any of the variables declared as an
> external array as mentioned in `__shared__`; `Ns` is an optional
> argument which defaults to 0;

Size of shared memory in my GPU is 48kB.
For example I want to run a kernel with 4 parallel blocks, every one of them uses 12kB of shared memory.

In order to do that, should I launch the kernel this way

```
kernel<<< gridSize, blockSize, 12 * 1024 >>>();
```

or should the third argument be `48 * 1024`?

Comment: The third argument specifies how much dynamically allocated shared memory is used by the kernel, so the third argument should be `12 * 1024`. But if you want to run four kernels in parallel, I expect you will be using streams, so there should be also a fourth argument in your kernel calls.

Comment: Thanks! By the way I meant not '4 kernels at the same time', but '1 kernel on 4 threadblocks at the same time'. I guess I still need to use `kernel<<< gridSize, blockSize, 12 * 1024 * 1024 >>>();`

Comment: I assume you mean `12*1024`, not `12*1024*1024`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ns in a size in bytes. If you want to reserve `12kB` of shared memory you would do `12*1024*1024`.

I doubt you want to do this. Ns value is `PER BLOCK`. So it is the amount of shared memory per block executing on the device. I'm guessing you'd like to do something around the lines of `12*1024*1024/number_of_blocks;`

**Kernel launching with concurrency:**
If as mentioned in a comment, you are using streams there is a fourth input in the kernel launch which is the cuda stream.

If you want to launch a kernel on another stream without any shared memory it will look like:

```
kernel_name<<<128, 128, 0, mystream>>>(...);
```

but concurrency is a whole different issue.

Comment: Yep, you're a right, I wanted 12 * 1024 * 1024, It was kind of misprint. Thank you for your answer.